# XAMPP - Server and client cannot communicate

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have written a very simple PHP program for adding data to MySQL RDBMS. The file works when I upload it to my hosting server.

I am using XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2 for testing. In it I am using Apache and MySQL. When I try to submit the form I am getting following error 
`Cannot POST /connect.php`.

While opening `localhost/test/connect.php` through a browser, it shows following error `Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ..\xampp\htdocs\test\connect.php on line 7`

Here's the line 7 `$firstName = $_POST('firstName');`

What to do to test my file using `XAMPP Control Panel` before uploading them to server?

Comment: remove `<?php
include('connect.php');
?>` this from your html file. it is not needed there

Comment: Also, the below answer is correct. the reason you're getting those errors is because you're including the `PHP` file on which those variables are not set in that instance. Your POST variables are only set when you submit the form.

Comment: Okay! This might sound funny. I followed the solution and added `if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['userName'])) {
    //code
}`. Further, tested it on a standardized  server. And Uploaded the html and php on webhosting account. The data was now submitted to the server. And it worked. However, I still receive the error in XAMPP. So, is it something with my XAMPP setting?
@hungrykoala

Comment: possible answer to that is in your standardized server error_reporting is turned off while in your xampp it is on. So just add `error_reporting(0);` to the top most of your php code just below `<?php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accessing the PHP with Brackets. So, it ran on a server independent from Apache within XAMPP. So, if you are using XAMPP make sure you place your files in htdocs and the path in your browser's address bar should look something like `localhost/folder(within htdocs)/file.html`. If you are facing the stated problem and this is not the case then **follow above answer and do read the comments**.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the `$_POST` array incorrectly.

Change the following:

```
$firstName = $_POST('firstName');
$userName = $_POST('userName');
```

To:

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$userName = $_POST['userName'];
```

Your undefined index error is because the fields aren't being set correctly (aka, you are loading the page without sending the form data). To fix this, wrap all your code in:

```
if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['userName'])) {
    //code
}
```

...or something similar (like killing the page if neither are set).

This error:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ..\xampp\htdocs\test\connect.php on line 7
```

Is because you were treating `$_POST` like a variable function by placing `()` after it.

Also, you need to use prepared statements as you are currently vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I will make note of prepared statement. I made the suggested changes please read till end. After making these changes I receive different error given in the post.

Comment: Yes I'm aware, hence you need to check if they are both set before assigning them to individual variables.

Comment: The code worked in tutorial so I thought it should work for me as well

Comment: I placed all the code starting from $conn variable to $conn->close in the `if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['userName'])) {
    //code
}`. I am still getting the same error cannot connect to POST and undefined index.